# Is it possible to get single shared access signature for all the container in storage account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service, azure-storage-account

As the title says, I'm looking for a single `shared access signature` to access all the containers present in a storage account.

Currently I have to get `shared access signature` for each container separately to create separate `EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` for each container which I'm trying to avoid

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible to do so. What you will need to do is get `Account Shared Access Signature (Account SAS)`.

Depending on the permissions granted in Account SAS, it will be applicable to all blob containers (and blobs) in that storage account.

You can learn more about Account SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegating-access-with-a-shared-access-signature.

From the link mentioned above:

> An account-level SAS, introduced with version 2015-04-05. The account
>   SAS delegates access to resources in one or more of the storage
>   services. All of the operations available via a service SAS are also
>   available via an account SAS. Additionally, with the account SAS, you
>   can delegate access to operations that apply to a given service, such
>   as Get/Set Service Properties and Get Service Stats. **You can also
>   delegate access to read, write, and delete operations on blob
>   containers, tables, queues, and file shares that are not permitted
>   with a service SAS**. See Constructing an Account SAS for more
>   information about account SAS.

Comment: Thanks for this. I got the sas from storage account. But now I'm facing issue in using it in external data source. I'll try for some more time and see if I can fix it.

Comment: Will it be possible to ask a separate question for that? I am not sure I understand `external data source` thing you mentioned.

Comment: Sure I'll ask. Its about using the sas in sql server `BULK INSERT`